# How to restrict users to push data or adding child more than one to firebase database child

Tags: javascript, json, security, firebase, rules

In firebase security rules how do we restrict users to push data more than one to the database?

I've been trying this but didn't work

```
   {
    "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,    
    "voters": {

  // restrict user to adding child more than one in this path
  // one user only alowed to add one child
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth !== null",
  ".validate": "newData < 2",
    "$votersuid": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid == $votersuid",
    }   
  },
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a boolean to your node and then you can test like this `".write": "root.child('node_name').child('can_write').val() === true`

Comment: thanks for your reply I still need to test it, unfortunately I can't vote up your answer since my reputation is under 15.